# UICollectionView cell overlapping with Header

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uicollectionview

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let collectionViewWidth = collectionView.bounds.width


        let keys = Array(indoordataDictionary.keys)
        let keyString:String = keys[indexPath.section]
        let objFacilityUserList:FacilityUserList = indoordataDictionary[keyString]! as! FacilityUserList

        if objFacilityUserList.facilityUserList.count == 1 {
            return CGSize(width: collectionViewWidth, height: 30)
        }
    return CGSize(width: collectionViewWidth/2, height: 70)
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 5
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {

    if indoorSegment.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {
        return CGSize(width:collectionView.frame.size.width, height:0.0)
    }
    else {
        return CGSize(width:collectionView.frame.size.width, height:40.0)
    }
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

    let headerView: PlaceCollectionReusableView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: TagIDConstant.nibs.kPlaceCollectionReusableViewID, for: indexPath) as! PlaceCollectionReusableView
    let keys = Array(indoordataDictionary.keys)
    let keyString:String = keys[indexPath.section]
    headerView.placeNameLabel.text = keyString

    return headerView
}
```

Comment: put screen shot of overlapped header

Comment: Check the height of your section header. Check if it isn't returning 0 in which case it will look like the cells are overlapping header.

Comment: Try to override referenceSizeForHeaderInSection method and return  your desired height